# Automate dynamic IMPORTRANGE in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a multi-section questionnaire (3 in total) and I want to have 4 sheets to hold the data (one master and one for each section).

How would I send data to another sheet from the master spreadsheet when a new row is added to the Master Sheet and make it dynamic so it does not pull the same row everytime?

I have found this script online:

[script link](https://script.google.com/d/MzSJAGEApgrozDHL0ZYesz5xAmkLRUCMw/edit?mid=ACjPJvHjH7blwJ1nepaBjjGKoVTBPa8NmTea9TepbRXbmZEyDQH4vmc-1byfVQSjkQnrff0qYVdc0GStsAjBm571oCkBGM1_6aWpeyLw2FM76ZYYAPyHNWi73vtmrUf1xocaIHEkor0N1jU&uiv=2)

but it is for moving data between sheets unfortunately. Could it be remodeled?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not able to completely understand your question.  What do you mean by "When a new row is added"? Do you mean to add info to a row or add a whole new row to the Spreadsheet? What do you mean by " it is for moving data between sheets, unfortunately". I don't understand your goal and please set your file public or grant me permissions to see it.

Comment: Reading your code and to be sure of what you want. When data is inserted into a row in your master sheet from a form submit, do you want to move that data automatically to the other "Completed" sheet?

Comment: Hi Alberto, correct. I mean when someone completes a form. I have the form natively integrated with google sheets so the master sheet is automatically updated. I want to be able to automate the sending of that form data to another sheet

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the setFormula class can help you, it can be dynamic & you can update it with a trigger

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL", "SHEET_NAME!'+rangevariable1inA1notation+':'+rangevariable2inA1notation+'")');
```

Make sure you get the range you want, and the notation of those 2 variables to get the dynamic range:

```
var rangevariable1inA1notation = sheet.getRange(1,1).getA1Notation(); // for example, instead of 1,1 it could be your own variable
var rangevariable2inA1notation = sheet.getRange(2,2).getA1Notation(); //for example
```

Answer (score 0):

To send values to another sheet (besides from your main one), you can use the [`onFormSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) function, it will be triggered every time the form is submitted and with its [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit), which contains the information from your form, you will be able to pass those values into the other sheets as you want.

```
// This will be triggered every time the form is submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Get all sheets in the active spreadsheet
  var sheetsArr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  // Get the second sheet
  var slaveSheet1 = sheetsArr[1];
  // Get the row where the values will be inserted 
  var rowVals = slaveSheet1.getLastRow() + 1;
  // The number of cols where you will puth the values
  var numberOfCols = e.values.length;
  // Set values that came from the form
  slaveSheet1.getRange(rowVals, 1, 1, numberOfCols).setValues([e.values]);
}
```

Be careful with the installable triggers [***Restrictions***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions).